# Linq aggregate dictionary into new dictionary

Tags: c#, linq

```
class Key { string s; int i; }
```

Given a `Dictionary<Key,int>` I want a new `Dictionary<string,int>` that is a mapping of the minimum dictionary value for each Key.s over all keys.

I feel like this should be easy but I just can't get it.

Thanks

clarification:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<Key,int>();
dict.Add(new Key("a", 123), 19);
dict.Add(new Key("a", 456), 12);
dict.Add(new Key("a", 789), 13);
dict.Add(new Key("b", 998), 99);
dict.Add(new Key("b", 999), 11);
```

and I want to produce the dictionary:

```
 "a" -> 12
 "b" -> 11
```

hope that helps.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "the minimum dictionary value for each Key over all keys". A [mcve] with sample input and expected output data would be much more helpful than the question in its current form.

Comment: @JonSkeet question updated.

Comment: So you want to group the original dictionary's entries by the `s` property of the keys, then in each group you're interested only in the entry having the smallest dictionary value; then from all remaining dictionary entries, you build a new dictionary where the key is the original key's `s` property and the value is the original value?

Comment: Looks like he wants the Value of the dictionary by aggregating the string portion of the keys and finding the one with the max integer portion. Once that is found take the value in the dictionary for said key. Looks horrible

Comment: @stakx exactly right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not clear on exactly what you're trying to do, but you can do a mapping from one dictionary to another with `.Select(...` and/or `.ToDictionary(...`

For example:

```
Dictionary<Key, int> original = ...
Dictionary<string, int> mapped = original.ToDictionary((kvp) => kvp.Key.s, (kvp) => kvp.Key.i);
```

If you improve your question to be more clear, I'll improve my answer.

EDIT: (question was clarified)

```
var d = dict.GroupBy(kvp => kvp.Key.s).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Min(k => k.Value));
```

You want to group by the key `s` property, then select the minimum of the dictionary value as the new dictionary value.

Comment: @caesay i need the miniumum kvp.Value for each kvp.Key.s

Comment: @CoderBrien: there you go!

Comment: awesome, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

A more generic method to skip the `Lookup` that is created by `.GroupBy` :

```
    public static Dictionary<K, V> aggregateBy<T, K, V>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source,
        Func<T, K> keySelector,
        Func<T, V> valueSelector,
        Func<V, V, V> aggregate,
        int capacity = 0,
        IEqualityComparer<K> comparer = null)
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<K, V>(capacity, comparer);
        foreach (var t in source)
        {
            K key = keySelector(t);
            V accumulator, value = valueSelector(t);
            if (dict.TryGetValue(key, out accumulator))
                value = aggregate(accumulator, value);
            dict[key] = value;
        }
        return dict;
    }
```

Sample use:

```
    var dict = new Dictionary<Tuple<string,int>, int>();
    dict.Add(Tuple.Create("a", 123), 19);
    dict.Add(Tuple.Create("a", 456), 12);
    dict.Add(Tuple.Create("a", 789), 13);
    dict.Add(Tuple.Create("b", 998), 99);
    dict.Add(Tuple.Create("b", 999), 11);

    var d = dict.aggregateBy(p => p.Key.Item1, p => p.Value, Math.Min);

    Debug.Print(string.Join(", ", d));        // "[a, 12], [b, 11]"
```

Comment: i don't think i need it in this case but thanks for pointing out the inefficiency!